# Azure DevOps markdown preview in repo: heading anchors rendering as work item links

Tags: azure-devops, markdown

I have a markdown file in my Azure DevOps repo. The file has a TOC that uses heading anchors:

```
- [1. Abstract](#1.-abstract)
- [2. Table of contents](#2.-table-of-contents)
- [3. Introduction](#3.-introduction)
  - [3.1. Recommended reading](#3.1.-recommended-reading)

## 1. Abstract
...
## 2. Table of contents
...
## 3. Introduction
...
### 3.1. Recommended reading
```

The links work in vs code and any other editor that I use.
In Azure DevOps, when navigating to the file and selecting preview, the heading anchors are being rendered as Azure DevOps work item links:

[image]

Is there a way to use heading anchors without having them link to work items within Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of manually creating the anchor links you can use the [TOC directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/wiki-markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops#table-of-contents-toc-for-wiki-pages). It works not only in the wiki, but also in the preview pane for markdown files.

```
[[_TOC_]]

## 1. Abstract
...
## 2. Table of contents
...
## 3. Introduction
...
### 3.1. Recommended reading
```

The result will look like the following (The links are anchor links to each heading)

[image: Exmaple of how TOC looks]